# How to Structure Golang Modules and Project structure in the New way

Tags: go, go-modules

It seems that the way modules are used since 1.11 has changed , and I am trying to understand how to reference a module / package from another directory.

Lets say I have a folder structure
\root\module1
\root\module2

I have a go.mod in each directory and I can access / use those modules from the \root directory

How can I access module2 from module1.  The modules are not published anywhere ( nor do I want them to be ) - I just want to access them.  Module 2 contains types / structs that I need to use in mondule1

Kind Regards
Martin

Comment: See https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#can-i-work-entirely-outside-of-vcs-on-my-local-filesystem

Comment: Thanks @CeriseLimón - but I still don't get it.   If I put one go.mod in the root directory - I am expecting to access a package using import "mymodule/mysubdir/mypackage"  but it's not working

Comment: Follow the [example linked from the wiki page](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/1nYoAMFZVVM/eppaRW2rCAAJ).  Create a go.mod file in each module.  Change "hello" to "module1" and "goodbye" to "module2" to match the code in question.   Replace "example.com/me/" with whatever you want or use it as is.

Answer (score 8):

## OLD WAY

Go modules have to be placed in GOPATH for be used.

When i start a new go project, i usually create a folder into the gopath

```sh
cd $GOPATH
ls
```

Here you find 3 folder

```
bin  pkg  src
ls src
>code.cloudfoundry.org  github.com  github.ibm.com  golang.org  gopkg.in  go.uber.org  honnef.co  winterdrache.de
```

Into src, there are the code that you retrieve using 'go get' command.

Everything that is here can be imported(/exported) into your software.

Assume this test project:

```
github.ibm.com/
└── Alessio-Savi
    └── GoLog-Viewer
        ├── conf
        │   ├── dev.json
        │   └── test.json
        ├── database
        │   ├── cloudant
        │   │   └── cloudant.go
        │   └── db2
        │       └── db2.go
        ├── datastructure
        │   └── datastructures.go
        ├── GinProva.go
        ├── README.md
        ├── request
        │   └── request.go
        └── resources
            └── template01.html
```

NOTE: Data structure are saved in a go file in a properly directory for avoid circle-import

You can import the datastructures.go (or another file that you need) using the following import statement

```golang
package mypackage

import(
    "github.ibm.com/Alessio-Savi/GoLog-Viewer/datastructure"
)
```

In other file (in the same project as in other) you can simply use the package and let the IDE help you (due to the fact the the module/project is in GOPATH)

[image]

## New way

In order to create a new module, you can use the new `go module init` gotool command.

A common way for create a new module, in case of public source code, is the follwing:

```sh
go mod init github.com/username/modulename
```

This will generate two file:

1. go.mod
2. go.sum

The `go.mod` file will contain every library/external golang code necessary to run your module.
The `go.sum` file will contain the hash of the library.

I'll use for example my little general purpose library, called `GoGPUtils`.

```sh
mkdir GoGPUtils
cd $_
go mod init github.com/alessiosavi/GoGPUtils
```

Now, you can insert the library that you need in your code in the `go.mod` library. Assume that you need the `ahocorasick` implementation for work with string search, the `go.mod` file will contains the following content:

```
module github.com/alessiosavi/GoGPUtils

go 1.13

require (
    github.com/alessiosavi/ahocorasick v0.0.3
    golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20191031220737-6d8f1af9ccc0 // indirect
)
```

In the `require` section, there are the list of package needed. Now you can import the `ahocorasick` library in your code as following:

```golang
import (
    ahocorasick "github.com/alessiosavi/ahocorasick"
)
```

Comment: Apparently not any more  https://www.melvinvivas.com/go-version-1-11-modules/#targetText=Modules%20are%20a%20collection%20of%20related%20Go%20packages.&targetText=With%20the%20current%20version%201.11,search%20for%20source%20code%20dependencies.

Comment: Updated with the new `go mod init`

Comment: I have 2 folders inside a root folder, module1 and module2 when i initialized both with go mod, and used the 2nd one inside first one, i couldn't get it, package x is not found in GOROOT

Comment: Have you insert the second dependencies into the first `go.mod` file? If the project is open source, please share the link