# Error cannot find package "github.com/go-redis/redis/v8" when downloading go-redis package

Tags: go, redis, go-redis

I tried to download go-redis using this command `go get github.com/go-redis/redis/v8` but I got this following error :

```
cannot find package "github.com/go-redis/redis/v8" in any of:
        C:\Go\src\github.com\go-redis\redis\v8 (from $GOROOT)
        E:\Go Workspace\src\github.com\go-redis\redis\v8 (from $GOPATH)
```

Why did I get this error and how to fix this ?

```
OS : Windows
Go version : go version go1.15 windows/amd64
```

Comment: Please use only module builds. GOPATH builds are basically deprecated.

Comment: i see. so there's no way i can install redis-go without using go module ?

Comment: Look at the following response in order to structure your project using the `go modules`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57944766/9361998

Comment: @PajriAprilio You are already using Go 1.15 and you have modules by default only. And it's much better than the `go get` way; trust me. So, please use that. Very simple to use!

Comment: It is dead simple to "install" redis-go without modules, but there is no point. If you cannot get it running  with modules you won't be able to do it properly in GOPATH mode either. Modules are the future. Get used to them now.

Comment: i see. thank you all. i'll use go module for my future project.

Answer (score 1):

Following steps solved my problem:

1. Initialize the go module (since go-redis supports last 2 Go versions & requires support for [Go Modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules)

```
go mod init github.com/my/repo
```

2. Install redis/v8 using the command

```
go get github.com/go-redis/redis/v8
```

Create a main.go file and write the following code to check for your connection

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/go-redis/redis/v8"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Go Redis Connection Test")

    client := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr: "localhost:6379",
        Password: "",
        DB: 0,
    })

    pong, err := client.Ping().Result()
    fmt.Println(pong, err)

}
```

When we will run this now, we will see that the Go application will successfully ping the redis instance and it will return a successful PONG response:

```
go run main.go
```

[image]